# ArrayList filled with 1D Arrays, cant access Values in Arrays

Tags: java

I'm putting 1D Arrays in an Array List

```
ArrayList<int[]> pairs_ref = new ArrayList();
int[]singlePair_ref = new int [2];


singlePair_ref[0] = 15;
singlePair_ref[1] = 0;

pairs_ref.add(singlePair_ref);

return pairs_ref;
```

However, an test output on the console only shows Zeros, not the correct values

```
 pairs_ref = object_ref.methodFillsArrayListAsShownAbove();

 for (int t = 0;t<pairs_ref.size();t++){

        int[]array_ref = pairs_ref.get(t);
        System.out.println("Live: "+array_ref[0]+"  "+array_ref[1]);

    }//endfor
```

this Version brings the same result

```
 int[]array_ref = new int[2];
 for (int t = 0;t<pairs_ref.size();

 array_ref = pairs_ref.get(t);
        System.out.println("Live: "+array_ref[0]+"  "+array_ref[1]);
        System.out.println(pairs_ref.get(t));}
```

Why is this? Is it the putting or the getting of the variables of the ArrayList? 
Thanks in Advance!
Daniel

Comment: no repro! seems to work fine for me. See http://ideone.com/q8F9y

Comment: Can you fix that second version? Something seems to be missing, at least part of the for declaration.

Comment: no repro, you mean creating the output array once and save the array via .get(t) in the same instance over and over again, like my 2nd version?

Comment: @Thomas, yes you need to add the pairs_ref = object_ref.Method...() from the first version too, sorry bout that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that as of Java 5 your code can be simplified:

```
ArrayList<int[]> pairs_ref = new ArrayList<int[]>(); //note the use of generics in the parameter
int[] singlePair_ref = new int [2];
singlePair_ref[0] = 15;
singlePair_ref[1] = 0;

pairs_ref.add(singlePair_ref);

//simplification here
for (int[] arr : pairs_ref){
    System.out.println("Live: "+arr[0]+"  "+arr[1]);
}
```

This should work at your system.

Comment: yes! that worked, i fixed it like the latter. Thanks to all of you guys!

Answer (score 2):

If this is the observed output for you, something else is wrong in your code.

The program below (verbatim copy of the snippets you provided) outputs the expected result:

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {

    public static ArrayList<int[]> methodFillsArrayListAsShownAbove() {
        ArrayList<int[]> pairs_ref = new ArrayList();
        int[] singlePair_ref = new int[2];

        singlePair_ref[0] = 15;
        singlePair_ref[1] = 0;

        pairs_ref.add(singlePair_ref);

        return pairs_ref;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<int[]> pairs_ref = methodFillsArrayListAsShownAbove();

        for (int t = 0; t < pairs_ref.size(); t++) {

            int[] array_ref = pairs_ref.get(t);
            System.out.println("Live: " + array_ref[0] + "  " + array_ref[1]);

        }// endfor

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Live: 15  0
```

**Ideone.com demo**
[Link](http://ideone.com/kAtcJ)

Comment: just one thing: In the Method "methodFillsArray...()" I fill the singlePair_ref Array in a for-loop, so I overwrite the values in the indexes singlePair_ref[0] and singlePair_ref[1] over and over again. Could this be the Problem?

Comment: Oh, yes. You have to create a new array in each iteration!

Comment: change to `pairs_ref.add(new int[] {15, 0});` and it should work fine.